# Have there been any attempts at classifying patent classes

Tags: us-class

Have there been any attempts at classifying patent classes?  I can see that the design classes is one group.  I am wondering if it is possible to create groups such as chemistry, manufacturing, etc.  Or even at a abstract level for things like processes, widgets.  I realize that there will be overlap and cross references.

I am looking for a grouping of patent classes.

Comment: @George White's answer was 'correct'.  However, keeping this open in case there are other responses.

Answer (score 1):

Look no further, it has been done, at least twice!

The examination corp is organized into Technology Centers.

[image]

Under that level are Art Units and each art unit is responsible for a handful of classes.

The USPTO recently started transitioning to a new joint US/EPO classification system called CPC that is based on the European system but with more granularity in the leaf nodes. Like the international system, it has a logical top level:

[image]

Comment: For the patent tech. centers, I can't seem to figure out how I find the related classes, e.g., for 1600 which are the patent classes.  for the CPC, I assume I need to map the CPC classes to the USPTO classes?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.uspto.gov/patents/resources/classification/art/index.jsp